# Raspberry Pi 2 model B Ubuntu Trusty 14.04

Tags: 14.04, raspberrypi, boot

I have met problems with Raspberry Pi 2 model B Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 installation.

I've uploaded Ubunty Trusty 14.04 build from Ryan Finnie. I have Windows 10. Then I used SD formatter to clean microSD, then Win32Imager, to make bootload flash card, as described in raspberry tutorials.
It turned out, only colorful screen is showed at my attached monitor. Board LEDs act like board is trying to boot up but it can't, so it starts over and over again. Maybe someone solved those problems.