# Why does ubuntu 14.04 arm v7 load only a coloured screen on my raspberry pi 2 model b

Tags: 14.04, raspberrypi, arm

This is the link to the version I etched onto my micro sdhc card earlier http://www.finnie.org/software/raspberrypi/2015-04-06-ubuntu-trusty.zip

[This link is to the image of the screen as it has been for 11 HOURS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32gSB.png)

[Raspberry Pi 2 model B Ubuntu Trusty 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883207/raspberry-pi-2-model-b-ubuntu-trusty-14-04?rq=1)

Comment: Just a wild stab in the dark - but how many amps does the power source have? I've seen strange behaviour similar to this, and it was due to the USB power source not providing sufficient amperage. In that particular instance, a 2amp USB power adapter solved the issue.

Comment: I used both a 1.8 Amp and a 3.0 Amp adapter

Answer (score 1):

It could be a couple of things.  The image you are using is not compatible with the RPI Hardware version or the SD card you are using is not loading.  I would get a new SD, image it, and see if it will boot.  It seems like Raspbian is compatible with all Pi hardware types.  Good Luck!

Comment: If I wanted Raspbian I would have purchased a card that already had it on.

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific, the kernel fails to load.

There could be a number of reasons for it starting from the sdcard not being imaged properly to incompatible kernel image or the kernel image file itself may be missing.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. 2015-04-06-ubuntu-trusty.img on SanDisk Ultra PLUS 16GB in a Pi 2 Model B V2.1

Tried 2.5A power Supply, no luck

Booted Raspian, Ubuntu 16.04 no problems

Comment: You require a raspberry pi 2 model b v1.1